# Responsive background image CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-transitions

I have a screenshot class similar to screenshots found on dribbble.com, when I hover over it I display a link icon. I made it responsive up untill the part where my background image(the link icon) stays the same size and it looks really large when I downscale the rest.

How can I make sure that the background img of the link-icon class downsizes aswell when I scale down the browser?

```
.screenshot .link-icon {
    background: url("../img/icons/link.png") #fff no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8.02139037433155%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 39%;
    left: 42.25352112676056%;
}
```

So I kind of need to make my background url image responsive. Hope I said it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the height for that purpose:

```
.screenshot .link-icon {
    background: url("../img/icons/link.png") #fff no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 8.02139037433155%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 39%;
    left: 42.25352112676056%;
    height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: No change in behaviour when I change it to this.

Comment: what height did you define? I have placed 1em just for eg. It would be best using pixel.